# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column with no primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table:

```
Ratings
---
PersonId int FKEY
FormId int FKEY
Rating int (NULLABLE)
```

When I perform this query:

```
INSERT INTO Ratings (PersonId, FormId)
SELECT p.PersonId, f.FormId
FROM People p, Forms f
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Ratings' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

At one point I had accidentally set the two foreign key columns to a composite primary key, and I fear there may be a form of data corruption.  What can I do to remedy this or to repair my issue in the long-run?

Comment: As the error message suggests, you need to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` if you want to explicitly set the value.

Comment: I realize, but I shouldn't have to do that, there is no primary key and I've done similar queries with other tables.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure why you're mass-inserting the ratings records without any values (or even allowing `null` ratings) - you could simply use the fact that they _don't_ have a record in this table to record such a state.

Comment: The table is named poorly but the relationship between People and Forms must be maintained even if that person has never placed a rating on that form.  The mass insert is really only being done with a small existing network of users which will have access to all forms.

Answer (score 1):

Please revise your Ratings table structure. One of the columns, either PersonId or FormId, is configured as an IDENTITY columns (a sequence), which makes no sense because both are FKs pointing to other tables. You should remove the IDENTITY property from the column (being it either PersonId or FormId) in this table.

Comment: I had accidentally created a composite key with them at one point.  I've long removed it but its effects continue on.  SQL Server does not detect a primary key (or any keys, since I wiped everything) but the restriction continues.  I ended up just deleting the table and making a new one with the same configuration (as creating the same schema with the same table name did not fix the problem).

Comment: @jokulmorder Whether a column is an identity column is independent of whether it is part of any key. Consequently, removing keys does not change a column to no longer be an identity column.

Comment: I realize but I did not set the identity specification to true. I know you are convinced that this is simply a configuration problem but dropping the table did not allow me to recreate a new table with that name.  That is why I believed it was an issue with SQL Management Studio.  The connection I am on is not very good so I am less adverse to ruling out data corruption between the server and my client.

Comment: @jokulmorder (To clarify, I'm not the one who posted this answer.) It's certainly conceivable that SSMS has a bug, where dropping the table fails but for some reason doesn't cause a proper error message to be shown. To rule out such problems, you can avoid the table designer (or even avoid SSMS completely) and use the appropriate SQL statements to drop and re-create the table. If you prefer, you can use SSMS to generate the script for you, and simply execute it outside of SSMS.

Comment: I apologize for any sharpness in tone; it's just a very frustrating problem.  I will continue trying with scripts and queries.  I did manage to have some success by creating a table and renaming it to the dropped table, but dropping that table did not appear to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This script demonstrates how `IDENTITY_INSERT` is working. Please check - there are no `PRIMARY KEY` defined.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tool(ID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(40)) 
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Tool 
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tool ON 
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Tool (ID, Name) VALUES (3, 'Garden shovel') 
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Tool 
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Tool
GO
```

Comment: I am 100% sure there is no primary key for the table.  Is the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to true by default for tables without a primary key?

Comment: No there are no such default behaviour - you need to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON **explicitly**

Comment: So it would seem as though there is a data corruption issue.  Is there a way to fix this through SQL Server?

Comment: What's in my original post is pretty much it: just a table with 2 foreign key columns that were at one point a composite primary key by accident.  I've deleted the table already but I can create a new one with the same name and see if it still has those problems.  Doing that the first time did not fix the issue.

Comment: I cannot even create a new table with this table name since it thinks the old table still exists (not visible in management studio).  I am going to reboot the database server and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: good luck :) - but better try to read again the answer from @dean. I think you do not really understand what you're doing

Comment: All I did was delete a primary key that was added mistakenly.  I don't think any of this should have occurred as a result of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to SET IDENTITY_INSERT   ON

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  [Table] ON
--Write your Insert  Query
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  [Table] OFF
```